# Simple app with search from database in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-applications

I need to create a simple ruby on rails application. Databases is already created. I need to have an interface to search in the database.

My database:

```
name   |    url      |
======================
xyz    |www.xyz.com  |
======================
```

Web page should have a simple text field where I can give name as input and a button. Clicking the button should return me the name and url.

This is not a homework problem as I am no longer a student :). But this needs to be done urgently that's why I don't have time to go through the entire tutorials.
As I am entirely new to RoR I have no idea how to start with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest looking at the railscasts here:

http://railscasts.com/?search=search&tag_id=30&utf8=%E2%9C%93

Almost 20 episodes to get you started!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am following http://railscasts.com/episodes/37-simple-search-form. I have a question. In the tutorial the line <% form_tag projects_path, :method => 'get' do %>. What does projects_path means. I know Project is the table. But how does the app know about this variable. I am getting **undefined local variable or method `actressess_path' for #<#<Class:0x996b6e0>:0x8ce3e2c>** this error where Actresses is my table name.

Comment: Please post your model files and routes file. Then I can help more. How was your database created? Did you use rails generate / migrate? RoR uses activerecord so it is probably worth looking at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

Comment: I think I am running out of time and I am gonna submit whatever I have and stop working on this project. But your answer was exactly what I was looking for so I am gonna accept it. Thanks for your time.